# Ubuntu Popcorn Time TV Stick

Tags: hdmi

I purchased a "PC on a Stick" Intel Atom cpu, 2gb ram, 32gb storage. It currently runs Win 8.1. I want to install Ubuntu, and have it boot straight from "power on" into Popcorn time, not allowing the user to do anything else. I am new to anything Linux. Would this be possible? How do I go about getting this done...?

Comment: "PC on a stick" is a generic name describing a type of device. What is the exact name and brand of yours ?

Comment: http://www.takealot.com/proline-pc-on-a-stick-micro-computer/PLID34268527

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is very well possible. Just install Ubuntu, install Popcorn Time, make sure it runs OK, then add Popcorn Time to your Startup Programs. Nothing unusual here.

Comment: I need all other functionality that Ubuntu offers to be hidden from the user. Only the ability to run Popcorn time.

Comment: I had taken "no other uses" to mean: "I am not going to use it for anything else" rather than "I don't want the user to do anything else with it". There was no mention of any other user in your question.